# Syntax for Passing and Invoking Async Callbacks as a React Props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm wondering what the right syntax is for passing, then invoking async calls through React components. Specifically:

Often, I'll have a function like this:

```
const doAsync = async (obj) => {
   await doSomethingAsync(obj)
}
```

...and then I'll pass it down to a Component like this:

```
<>
   <MyComponent asyncCallback={doAsync} />
</>
```

I'm a little confused about a couple of things here:

1. Should I be passing the function down as
   `asyncCallback={doAsync(obj)}` or `asyncCallback={async () => await doAsync(obj)}` or just `asyncCallback={doAsync}`?
2. When this function is invoked, in say a `<button>`, should it be done like this `onClick={async (obj) => doAsync(obj)}` or `onClick={doAsync}`?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. 

Passing function like this `asyncCallback={doAsync}` is the best approach. You just pass this function as any other variable and this is ok.

Passing function like this `asyncCallback={async () => await doAsync(obj)}` also should work but it just to much boilerplate and you unnecessary make two new functions every rerender.

Passing it like this `asyncCallback={doAsync(obj)}` DOESN'T WORK because you dont pass this function you CALL IT in this place.

2.
You can do it like this `onClick={doAsync}` but you will pass `event` variable as an argument not your custom `obj` (if it's ok you can do it like this).

If you want to pass you custom `obj` variable you can pass it like this `onClick={() => doAsync(obj)}` (you don't need to use `async` or `await` keyword).